# How to solve trigonometry question

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve:

Solve for  $0°  \leq \theta \leq 360°$.
$$
\tan{\theta} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

Comment: Do you know how to solve $\tan \theta = 1/\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: Are you sure that's right?

Comment: In the range $0\le\theta\le360$ what are the other solutions?

Comment: That's what i need help with.

Comment: @random10101010 I have an answer that (might) help, but your question has been put on hold because you did not explain what you needed. Please use the "edit" link under the question to add the things you have said in comments (including the ones you deleted) about what you know about the angle already (you know how to solve $tan\theta = 1/\sqrt 3$, what's the answer?), what you learned in class, and what you forgot. Then we can see about reopening the question. Respond to me in a comment (use @ sign to tag me) when you have done these things.

Answer (score 2):

As we know $$\tan { \theta =a } \\ \theta =\arctan { a } +k\pi $$ so
$$\tan { \theta =-\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 3 }  }  } \\ \\ \theta =\arctan { \left( -\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 3 }  }  \right)  } +k\pi =-\frac { \pi  }{ 6 } +k\pi $$
take $k=1$ and $k=2$  $$k=1,{ \theta  }=-\frac { \pi  }{ 6 } +\pi =\frac { 5\pi  }{ 6 } \in \left[ 0,2\pi  \right] \\ k=2,{ \theta  }=-\frac { \pi  }{ 6 } +2\pi =\frac { 11\pi  }{ 6 } \in \left[ 0,2\pi  \right]  $$

Comment: You can produce the symbol $\in$ by typing \in when you are in math mode.

Comment: Thanks for editing @N.F.Taussig

Comment: @random10101010,iwe learn from each other,i have learnt a lot from this site personally me

Comment: @random10101010  You should explain why you do not understand the solution, which is correct.  Tell us what you know and what you have attempted so that we can write a response that is appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @random10101010 Which part confuses you? Where do you understand up to?

Answer (score 0):

$\tan\theta=-\dfrac1{\sqrt3}=\tan(-30 ^\circ)\iff \theta\equiv -30^\circ\mod 180^\circ.$